# Is there a limit to the number of items in a check box group?

Tags: checkbox, xpages, checkboxlist

I have a checkbox group for which I am using a @DbLookup to obtain the items to appear with checkboxes.  It works fine except for a couple of cases where I am getting over 230 values from the lookup.  In that case I get one checkbox with a value of "Infinity".  I think that is telling me I have too many choices in my checkbox group.

Is there a limit to the number of values you can put in a checkbox group?  What would be the best way to handle those cases where there is a large number of values?  I may just take the route of "if there are more than 100 values returned, truncate the list".

Comment: Can you categorize them? Let the users pick a category and then display the options for that specific category, rinse and repeat until they have selected all they want.

Comment: No, because these *are* the categories.  Good idea though.

Comment: Okay, how about breaking it up into manageable chunks by using an alphabetical list? Give them A-F, then G-M, etc.

Comment: Somehow I doubt this would be a good user interface vector... what is the business purpose of this particular checkbox group?

Comment: I agree with @TimTripcony - from UX standpoint I do not recommend checkbox with too many options (especially dynamic).

Comment: It is a list of storage box IDs. Each of the box IDs is a category with multiple documents in it.  I am having them select the box IDs for which all the documents in them should be marked for deletion.  Unfortunately, a couple of people have gotten behind on doing the deletions.  It has actually worked really well until now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no real limit for checkbox group. I tested it with 100000 entries and it still works well.

Probably, the "Infinity" error comes from `@DbLookup`. The error occurs if the result is larger than 64K. As an alternative to `@DbLookup` you can write your own SSJS code for getting the view entries or you use the [Pure Java version of DbLookup & DbColumn, with cache, sort and unique](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=pure-java-version-of-dblookup-dbcolumn-with-cache-sort-and-unique).